# Text overlapping in Android text view

Tags: android

I am facing a strange behavior of text view. When the text view has multiple lines, the lines are overlapping on each other. I tried to solve it but didn't get any clue yet.

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/googletv_bkgd_no_title"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="85dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingRight="50dip">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/navigationHeaderTxtView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#cccccc"
                android:visibility="gone" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" android:textColor="#ebebee" android:textStyle="bold"/>



        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
<!--    
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="top|right" android:layout_marginRight="20dip">



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_back" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnHome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_home" />

</LinearLayout>-->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_gravity="top" android:layout_marginTop="20dip" android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow_up"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_up" android:visibility="visible"/>

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="80dip" android:paddingRight="80dip">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dip"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dip"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:numColumns="5"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dip" >
    </GridView>

</FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_gravity="top" android:layout_marginTop="20dip" android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow_down"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_down" android:visibility="visible"/>

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/title_color"
        android:textSize="25dip" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

     <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textDescription"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have attached a screenshot regarding the problem.

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you show the portion of the layout XML where you are defining this `TextView`? Are you adjusting the line spacing, or are you using a custom font?

Comment: is that 2 different textview you are using?

Comment: Without XML Layout of TextView..its not possible to understand the thing cause you the error..!!

Comment: @Commonsware yes i am using a custom font and i am not adjusting any line spacing

Comment: @padma i am using only 1 text view

Comment: I got the solution.. The prob was due to using custom font. I just removed the custom font and the thing is get right automatically. But the thing is how to solve the prob when some body is using custom font..T

Comment: The real cause is the font's **lineHeight**.
The **lineHeight** can be set in Theme or in where you use the font.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to adjust your line spacing to accommodate the odd custom font, such as `android:lineSpacingExtra` on your `TextView`.