# TextView text printing over itself

Tags: android

I currently have a standard text view

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTaskDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvTaskName"
    android:text="Date"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

and I'm programmatically setting the font, textsize and text of the view.

```
font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Helvetica LT 75 Bold.ttf");
TextView tv = (TextView)(findViewById(R.id.tvTaskDate));
tv.setTypeface(font);
tv.setTextSize(20.0f);
tv.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("name"));
```

The issue is that it's coming out like this:

[image]

If I comment out the line that sets the font, the textView moves down to the next line and handles the text as it's suppose to. I attempted setting the `MaxLine()` property and it still behaves in the same manner.

Do I have to set an additional property when setting the typeface of a textView?

Comment: Use something like `android:lineSpacingExtra` in your TextView or look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470772/text-overlapping-in-android-text-view) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off Lokesh's comment above, using

```
tv.setLineSpacing(21.0f, 1);
```

Solved the issue. Since I was using a new font other than what comes standard with the textviews I had to define the spacing between the lines.